# How do I test a module that depends on boto and an Amazon AWS service?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I'm writing a very small Python ORM around `boto.dynamodb.layer2`. I would like to write tests for it, but I don't want the tests to actually communicate with AWS, as this would require complicated setup, credentials, network access, etc.

Since I plan to open source the module, including credentials in the source seems like a bad idea since I will get charged for usage, and including credentials in the environment is a pain.

Coupling my tests to the network seems like a bad idea, as it makes the tests run slower, or may cause tests to fail due to network errors or throttling. My goal is not to test boto's DynamoDB interface, or AWS. I just want to test my own code.

I plan to use [`unittest2`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2/) to write the tests and [`mock`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock/) to mock out the parts of boto that hit the network, but I've never done this before, so my question boils down to these:

1. Am I going about this the right way?
2. Has anyone else done this?
3. Are there any particular points in the `boto.dynamodb` interface that would be best to mock out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my questions fully:

1. As with @pcalcao's answer, mocking out the service was the right thing to do. It wasn't even as hard as I thought it would be--the test code is only marginally longer than the code under test, and most of it is tests, not plumbing.
2. Thanks to @gamaat for getting me to take a second look, boto *does* do this [in its own tests](https://github.com/boto/boto/tree/develop/tests/unit), mocking at the actual transport interface level, in `httplib`.
3. Mocking the `boto.dynamodb.layer1` interface (along with `boto.connect_dynamodb`) turned out to be the right thing to do. Setting spies on `boto.dynamodb.layer2` and `boto.dynamodb.table` also helped. Once I began to understand it, I found that [`mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) is a joy to work with.

[Here's my solution](https://github.com/eykd/duo/blob/master/test_duo.py), BSD licensed. <del>I'll be posting the entire library to PyPI once I've dog-fooded it a bit longer and put together some proper documentation.</del> [I've posted it to PyPI.](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/duo)

Comment: Although I wholeheartedly agree mocking the service calls was the right thing to do, looking at your code still looks like a whole lot of overhead to mock the services. I wish there was a better mocking tool w/o all the ceremonial setup. Thanks for putting this up, though, always helpful to see other people's testing patterns.

Comment: @Syrahn I'm with you. I've recently become aware of the [moto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moto/) project. Perhaps this will help?

Comment: Is there a moto3 that will support boto3?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have the right approach, you definitely don't want your tests tied up with actual communication with AWS. Mocking the service is definitely the right thing to do here.

Comment: Agreed. I thought mocking out the service would be much harder than it actually turned out to be. This encouragement was exactly what I needed.

Comment: That's the thing with most of mocking/unit testing, it seems much harder before you start doing it=)

Answer (score 3):

All tests in boto were originally integration tests that hit live service endpoints.  We still have those tests but have also started adding mocked unit tests.  You might want to check out what's there so far for examples.

Comment: Links would be helpful, but reading through the boto test code at https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/tests/unit/ it appears that the mocking occurs at the `httplib` level, which makes sense for boto.

Comment: Upon my initial examination of boto's code, I only saw the integration tests, and my heart despaired.